# Using Ajax to Post PHP variables to another file

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I want to post the PHP variables `$uid` and `$submissionid` to the file fblike.php.  Is the Ajax below formatted correctly to do this?

```
<?php


ob_start();
session_start();

$uid = $_SESSION['loginid'];

$submissionid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['submissionid']);
$_SESSION['submissionid'] = $submissionid;


?>


<head>


<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.pack.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
    $("a.connect_widget_like_button").live(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "action=vote_up&uid="+$(this).attr("uid")"&submissionid="+$(this).attr("submissionid"),
            url: "fblike.php",

        });
    });


}); 
</script>

</head>
```

Answer (score 2):

You dont really want to use expando attributes if you dont have to, especially since thise are links... i would jsut do:

```
<a href="fblike.php?ction=vote_up&uid=1&&submissionid=1">Like</a>
```

then you can do a simple:

```
$("a.connect_widget_like_button").live('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.post($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Now on the php side you need to be aware of where the values will be. If you pass the values as i have done in my example they will be in `$_GET` (even if its a POST request). If you pass them like you did in your original post then they will be in `$_POST`.

Comment: Thanks... I didn't use your exact solution but putting the URL in the href with the Facebook Like button led me down the right path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send the data as an array/object. Something like this should do the trick.

```
$(function(){
    $("a.connect_widget_like_button").live(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                action: "vote_up",
                uid: $(this).attr('uid'),
                submissionid: $(this).attr('submissionid')
            },
            url: "fblike.php"
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: While passing data as a hash is much easier to read (and i also prefer it) using a query string will work.